# How to display a path between multiple co-ordinates in javascript google map API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps

I want to create a path between multiple co-ordinates which come from an array and through direction service, I want to render the path between these co-ordinates. If you look at array of co-ordinates here :

```
var requestResource = [{"origin": {"lat": 26.4499, "lng": 80.3319},  
"destination": {"lat": 28.6139, "lng": 77.2090}}, {"origin": {"lat": 28.6139, 
"lng": 77.2090},"destination": {"lat": 28.9845, "lng": 77.7064}}];
```

I am trying to generate code with the following code but it gives me only a path between the last set of origin and destination.

```
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

var indiaLatlng = {lat: 28.6139, lng : 77.2090};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center : indiaLatlng,
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
var rendererOptions = {
preserveViewport: true,         
suppressMarkers:true
};
var requestResource = [{"origin": {"lat": 26.4499, "lng": 80.3319}, "destination": {"lat": 28.6139, "lng": 77.2090}}, {"origin": {"lat": 28.6139, "lng": 77.2090},"destination": {"lat": 28.9845, "lng": 77.7064}}];
for(var r in requestResource) {
    var resource = requestResource[r];
    var mapRequest = {
        origin : resource["origin"],
        destination : resource["destination"],
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    }
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    directionsService.route(mapRequest, function(result, status) {
        console.log(result);
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
        }
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have one `google.maps.DirectionsRenderer` object in your code.  Each time you set the directions, it overrides the previous display.  Create a new DirectionsRenderer for each route you want to display.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d4a7d4ne/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initialize() {
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

  var indiaLatlng = {
    lat: 28.6139,
    lng: 77.2090
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: indiaLatlng,
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  var rendererOptions = {
    preserveViewport: true,
    suppressMarkers: true
  };
  var requestResource = [{
    "origin": {
      "lat": 26.4499,
      "lng": 80.3319
    },
    "destination": {
      "lat": 28.6139,
      "lng": 77.2090
    }
  }, {
    "origin": {
      "lat": 28.6139,
      "lng": 77.2090
    },
    "destination": {
      "lat": 28.9845,
      "lng": 77.7064
    }
  }];
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var r in requestResource) {
    var resource = requestResource[r];
    var mapRequest = {
      origin: resource["origin"],
      destination: resource["destination"],
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    }
    bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(resource["origin"].lat, resource["origin"].lng));
    bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(resource["destination"].lat, resource["destination"].lng));
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    directionsService.route(mapRequest, function(result, status) {
      console.log(result);
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

        directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
      } else alert("directions request failed, status:" + status)
    });
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places&ext=.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```